# Travis ci encode env variables failing for other github users on project

Tags: django, travis-ci

I cannot seem to find anywhere that talks about how to allow travis ci encode env variables to work for other users on github. I am using travis ci with a django project. 
Current .travis.yml file:

```
language: python
python:
- 3.6
env:
  global:
  - secure: # encrypted string for SECRET_KEY
  - secure: # encrypted string for another settings KEY
  - secure: # encrypted string for another settings KEY
install:
- pip install -r requirements/requirements.txt
script:
- flake8 --count --quiet
- python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
- python manage.py test
```

This works fine for me when I push a patch up, travisci runs the checks fine. But when anyone else does (or even me using another github account) travis ci fails saying it cannot find SECRET_KEY which is one of the secure encoded env variables I have in .travis file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why this doesn't work but the following works.

Go to your project settings on Travis:

https://travis-ci.org/USER/REPO/settings

**or**

https://travis-ci.com/USER/REPO/settings

Depends on your Travis version.

Then, you can simply add your secret variables in this section:

> Environment Variables

Remember to check if the "Display value in build log" tile is not set to true.

Here's a sample for one of my project:

[image: Travis env]

Remember to **not** encrypt those variables.

You can then use them in your .travis.yml with the name you put on the settings page.

(In my case : CLIENT_ID, etc.)

You don't need to declare them anymore in your .travis.yml file.

Hope this helps.